# Can't launch camera using FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried this for so long and getting the error below, I also tried adding **Expanding** widget before **SizedBox**. These where the majority error lines ---> *RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#93ffd relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE* and --->*Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.*

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Cameras extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cameras({Key? key, required this.camera}) : super(key: key);

  final CameraDescription camera;

  @override
  _CamerasState createState() => _CamerasState();
}

class _CamerasState extends State<Cameras> {
  late CameraController _controller;
  //late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.camera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );

    //_initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Image.asset(
          "assets/appbar.png",
          height: 25,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body:
      SizedBox(
        height: 200,
        child: FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: _controller.initialize(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
              return CameraPreview(_controller);
            } else {
              // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            if (!_controller.value.isInitialized) {
              await _controller.initialize();
            }
            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _controller.takePicture();

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key? key, required this.imagePath})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code, I'm pasting the error below

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  GridView GridView:file:///E:/Apps/coach_app/lib/Screens/main_screens/profile/gallery.dart:79:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1375:15)
#1      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1436:6)
#2      RenderBox.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2331:12)
#3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1837:9)
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#6      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#8      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#10     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#12     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#14     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#18     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#19     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#21     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#23     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#24     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#25     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#27     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#29     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#30     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1097:7)
#31     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#32     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#37     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1388:11)
#38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#39     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#41     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#47     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#49     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#51     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#53     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#55     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#56     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3422:13)
#57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#60     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:745:15)
#61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#64     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#66     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#68     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#70     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#71     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#72     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#74     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#76     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#77     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1713:7)
#78     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:885:18)
#79     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:453:19)
#80     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#81     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#82     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#83     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#84     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#099eb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=462.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: down
...  crossAxisDirection: right
...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#a6bfa(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f8914, ScrollDirection.idle)
...  anchor: 0.0
RenderObject: RenderViewport#099eb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=462.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: down
  crossAxisDirection: right
  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#a6bfa(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f8914, ScrollDirection.idle)
  anchor: 0.0
...  center child: RenderSliverPadding#9931c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    geometry: null
...    padding: EdgeInsets.zero
...    textDirection: ltr
...    child: RenderSliverGrid#1e5e4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      geometry: null
...      no children current live
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#099eb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1929 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  GridView GridView:file:///E:/Apps/coach_app/lib/Screens/main_screens/profile/gallery.dart:79:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1929:12)
#3      RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1453:39)
#4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#7      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#13     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#15     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#17     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#20     RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:545:11)
#21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#24     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
#25     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:829:43)
#26     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:931:32)
#27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#30     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#31     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1097:7)
#32     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
#33     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:404:14)
#34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#35     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#38     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1388:11)
#39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#40     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#42     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#44     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#46     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#57     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3422:13)
#58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#59     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#61     _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:745:15)
#62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#63     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#65     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#73     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#75     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
#76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1858:7)
#77     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:165:14)
#78     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1713:7)
#79     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:885:18)
#80     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:453:19)
#81     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#82     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#83     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1143:15)
#84     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1080:9)
#85     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:863:7)
(elided 6 frames from class _AssertionError, class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#099eb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=462.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: MISSING
...  axisDirection: down
...  crossAxisDirection: right
...  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#a6bfa(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f8914, ScrollDirection.idle)
...  anchor: 0.0
RenderObject: RenderViewport#099eb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  needs compositing
  parentData: <none> (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=462.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
  axisDirection: down
  crossAxisDirection: right
  offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#a6bfa(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#f8914, ScrollDirection.idle)
  anchor: 0.0
...  center child: RenderSliverPadding#9931c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...    parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...    constraints: MISSING
...    geometry: null
...    padding: EdgeInsets.zero
...    textDirection: ltr
...    child: RenderSliverGrid#1e5e4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...      parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
...      constraints: MISSING
...      geometry: null
...      no children current live
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: try to remove `SizedBox` before `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing camera in initState.

```
late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

 @override
 void initState() {
super.initState();
_getAvailableCameras();
}

Future<void> _getAvailableCameras() async {
 _initCamera(widget.cameras[1]);
}

Future<void> _initCamera(
  CameraDescription description) async {
 _controller = CameraController(
     description, ResolutionPreset.max,
    enableAudio: true);

try {
  _initializeControllerFuture =
      _controller.initialize();
  // to notify the widgets that camera has been initialized and now camera preview can be done
  setState(() {});
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
}
```

Then in FutureBuilder future call _initializeControllerFuture

```
Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context)
                  .size
                  .height *
              0.75,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: FutureBuilder<void>(
            future:
                _initializeControllerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: It didn't work again, I guess there is something else missing. 
`Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`

Comment: Instead of using sizeedbox can you use simply Container?

Comment: Hey can you check this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660739/i-need-to-save-picture-in-a-specific-location-flutter)