# I need to save picture in a specific location flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to save picture in a specific location rather than in temporary location.

```dart
void _takePicture(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await _initializeCameraControllerFuture;

      final path =
      join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, '${DateTime.now()}.png');

      await _cameraController.takePicture(path);

      Navigator.pop(context,path);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338041/how-to-save-image-file-in-flutter-file-selected-using-image-picker-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the image into external storage directory for showing the image on gallery. Instead of getting temporary directory, obtain external storage directory.

```
final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

You need to provide the permission on `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your `android/app/src/main` folder

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then let's say that you want to create a folder named MyImages and add the new image to that folder,

```
final myImagePath = '${directory.path}/MyImages' ;
final myImgDir = await new Directory(myImagePath).create();
```

then write to the file to the path.

```
var kompresimg = new File("$myImagePath/image_$baru$rand.jpg")
  ..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(gambarKecilx, quality: 95));
```

for getting the number of files, just obtain the files to a list and check the length of the list

```
var listOfFiles = await myImgDir.list(recursive: true).toList();
var count = countList.length;
```

Or check [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338041/how-to-save-image-file-in-flutter-file-selected-using-image-picker-plugin)